# Microsoft Traslator Widget Notify/Auto

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am implementing Microsoft Translator Widget using Auto or Notify option.  Where is widget getting Language setting from Browse (IE) Internet.options Language or Windows control panel Regional settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used IE Internet.Options Language and choose [es-ES]